# highcharts responsive datalabels display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, responsive-design

Is there any way to set the dataLabels of the highcharts to not overlap for smaller sizes?

I have a chart which is [similar to this one](http://jsfiddle.net/elsevero/29XhX/43/) but what I'd like to achieve is:

- alternate the Y values (data Labels: 15, 40, and so on.)
- avoid text overlapping, instead of number I have: "Long text" which overlaps at iPhone size

Is there any other option without specifying the `x` and `y` position of the `dataLabels`?

```
{
  "x": 1400457600000,
  "y": 15,
  "dataLabels": {
      "x": 25,
      "y": -5,
      "style": {
         "color": "#000000"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/) example which detect a collision.

```
 events: {
                load: function() {
                    StaggerDataLabels(this.series);
                },
                redraw: function() {
                    var series = this.series;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        StaggerDataLabels(series);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
```

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Thanks for the answer, seems that your example is with multiple series but I only got one. Meaning that the datalabels of the points from the same series is overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate them with a customer formatter.  This function tracks how many times it's been called and only returns the label for the even calls:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    if (this.series.chart.dlFCalls == null){
                        this.series.chart.dlFCalls = -1;
                    }
                    this.series.chart.dlFCalls++;
                    if (this.series.chart.dlFCalls % 2 == 0){
                        return this.y;   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As far as fitting long text, I'd use a combination of [rotation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.dataLabels.rotation) and offset the y value up a bit.

Here's a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/29XhX/44/).

Comment: +1 for the answer! but when I've said alternate then I meant one value to be above the horizontal line, the next one to be under the line.
Rotation is not an option for me, I need to find somehow that the data labels doesn't overlap.