# Highcharts - Overlapping scatterplot labels are not readable

Tags: javascript, highcharts, collision-detection

I want to clearly display all data labels for a scatter chart made with highcharts.

I have a scatter chart where there is a chance the points could be overlapping or very close together. By default highcharts hides any overlapping labels but I require all labels to be visible.
I have tried setting 'allowOverlap: true'. This makes all labels show like I want, but the labels are not always readable.
Is there any cleaner way of ensuring all labels are visible on a scatter chart, or has anyone been able to detect and offset overlapping labels?

JSFiddle where only three of four labels are displayed:
https://jsfiddle.net/jholwell/vbc58Luh/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [[1, 1], [1.8, 1.8], [1.9, 1.8], [5, 2]],
        type: 'scatter'
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        }
      }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts currently [doesn't have collision detection for labels](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/15960472-collision-detection-for-data-labels), but building on [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755464/1869660), you can implement your own collision detector (here: `staggerDataLabels()`) and run it on the chart's `load` and `redraw` events:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        staggerDataLabels(this.series);
      },
      redraw: function() {
        staggerDataLabels(this.series);
      }
    },
  },
  ...
});

function staggerDataLabels(series) {
  ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vbc58Luh/2/

Comment: I know this is an old thread. The https://jsfiddle.net/vbc58Luh/2/ is no longer valid. Can you post the function staggerDataLabels(series) code?

Comment: @FlyFish - What, do they delete old fiddles now? I don't have that code anymore, but I'm sure it was very similar to the original example from the linked question: http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/1/

Comment: I didn't know they deleted fiddles either. Thanks, that gives me a start.